# Upload app to App Store with MacOS 10.12

Tags: ios, iphone, publish

I made an app using PhoneGap that I now want to upload to the App Store.

I wanted to use the XCode Application Loader but I can't seem to be able to download XCode not being on High Sierra as I want to wait for the next MacOS version due to the bad reviews of High Sierra.

I tried downloading Application Loader 3.1 from iTunes Connect but it seems like it doesn't let me log in.

Is there any way to upload an app to the app store with MacOS Sierra?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple web pages](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/):

> **Build with iOS 11 SDK**
>
> Update your version of Xcode to the latest release of Xcode 9 available on the Mac App Store, which includes the iOS 11 SDK, and build your apps. Starting July 2018, all new iOS apps and updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK. All new iOS apps and updates for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.

So if you are building against the iOS 11 SDK, you should be able to submit your app. If you are not, you can't.